# How to retrieve again, the user data from Facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a bunch of data in a table from users who authorized the app on my site, but the data is corrupted, I have users with profile id registered and users without this information, users with only part of the data, without names, etc.

I need to update theses data, and get the profile id for all of them, so how do I retrieve again the data from Facebook for all theses users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get a list of users who authorized your App, which is what you would need. You can only get the ID (or any data) the next time they visit your App. Except you have stored an Extended Access Token that is still valid, but i guess that´s not the case.